# node.js: How to make a variable out of a text input?

Tags: node.js, variables, input, transformation

I want a user to put in a name of a file, then copy the content into an array and save this array with the name of the input filename. Here is the code I am talking about:

The array "items" represents the user input. Right now those items are fed into my function "einlesen" which returns the array with the data. This data is now written into the same array results but I want it to be written into the arrays "GVZ", "TAL", and "XPG". Can someone help me out?

Grateful for every idea :)

Nils

```
var items = [['GZV', ';', 1, 2], ['TAL', '<|>', 1, 'n'], ['XPG', '<|>', 0, 2]];
var results = [];

items.forEach(function(item) {
  einlesen.einlesen(item[0], item[1], item[2], item[3], function(err, result){
    results.push(result[1][0]);
    console.log(item[0]);
    if(results.length == items.length) {
    final();
    }
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off using an object instead of an array of arrays:

```
var items = {
    GZV: [...],
    TAL: [...],
    XPG: [...]
}

for(item in items) {
    einlesen.einlesen(...)
}
```

This way, you can create object properties based on user input. It is not possible to create a variable *(presuming you mean variable name?)* out of user input.

```
var newProp = "resultOfInput";
items[newProp] = [...];
console.log(items.resultOfInput) // [...]
```

If you're doing this, you need to ensure that there's strong validation on the input. For example; if the input contains any spaces this will prevent the property being accessed via dot notation. Worse still, duplicate user input could easily over-ride any existing properties in the array.

Comment: Thank you Matt, over-riding wont be a problem the created var name is only for further programming and will be deleted in the end. I will try using an object.